# IllegalArgumentException when using SpinnerItem in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I am trying to use a SpinnerItem as the editor type for a `ListGridField`

```java
final ListGridField quantityGridField = new ListGridField("quantity", "Cantidad");
quantityGridField.setEditorType(SpinnerItem.class);
quantityGridField.setCanEdit(true);
```

But after I compile the project and deploy it this error comes up.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No BeanFactory has been registered for: com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.SpinnerItem
```

This is the first time that I get this error and I have not found any related question here.

Answer (score 0):

As it's described in javadoc to the method that you use (setEditorType(class)) you use Reflection mechanism of smartgwt. You can read about it here: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Reflection.html .
According to this documentation you should register SpinnerItem(which is a subclass of FormItem) prior of using it:

> Similarly, to register FormItem and all its subclasses found in the
>   classpath (including your custom subclasses), you can use the
>   BeanFactory.FormItemMetaFactory.
>
> GWT.create(BeanFactory.FormItemMetaFactory.class);

So just try to insert this GWT.create line somewhere in your code before using it, so gwt compiler will be able to find your editor.